# Python/Django and sessions problems

Tags: python, django, session, cookies

I've a weird issue with Django sessions I'm struggling with. Basically my session is created correctly but for some reason I can't retrieve the content of the session_data afterwards.

Here is the basic step-by-step guide

Step 1: I access the homepage and (as expected) I don't have a valid session yet.

`HOMEPAGE: SESSION VALUE
session_key: None
userSecureId: None
END HOMEPAGE: SESSION VALUE`

Step 2: I log in, generate a session on Django and then redirect the user to his section

Here is how my session is generated and how redirect my user:

    `context = RequestContext(request)
    request.session['userSecureId'] = verify_token['userSecureId']
    request.session.set_expiry(3600)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('http://mywebsite/portal/'+verify_token['userSecureId'], context)`

Here's what I found on the log (I just print this right before doing the HttpResponseRedirect):

`AUTH PAGE: SESSION VALUE
session_key: None
userSecureId: 4d9f6a58-0ad4-4a4b-8191-bbfc8e397afe
END AUTH PAGE: SESSION VALUE`

So as of now, Django has created my session and is able to retrieve the value of userSecureId

Step 3: For some reasons, the value of userSecureId is lost during the ResponseRedirect. At this time my web application detect my cookie and is able to retrieve the session key but the userSecureId returns 'None'

`HOMEPAGE: SESSION VALUE
session_key: co5nknkz7kmka82f5130098gxoyvxkf8
userSecureId: None
END HOMEPAGE: SESSION VALUE`

Just to confirm my session is correctly configured on Django side, if I decode session_data of django_session where session_key = 'co5nknkz7kmka82f5130098gxoyvxkf8', then I'm able to retrieve the value correctly (meaning userSecureId exist)

Another problem is this code works perfectly on my local system. So I'm just wondering if I'm missing something. I'm using a remote database to store the session informations, and I have already confirmed my remote system can contact the database.

I tried to change my settings.py (eg: adding `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE,SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN,SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY,SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` but none of them seems to affect the general behavior of my app

Any idea on what may be

Answer (score 0):

Don't put "secure tokens" into the URL path. URLs a stored in the browser history and many other places. They are *public*, and not "secure".

Django will create a session ID for you, and if you switch the session cookie to `http_only` (using `SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY=True` in settings) and use the automatically created `csrf_token` too, then its already secure.

Simply do

```
HttpResponseRedirect('http://mywebsite/portal/')
```

And then in the view function for that page, check if the user is authenticated (there is a @decorator for that).

Regarding your question, you are using `session` correctly.

```
request.session['mykey'] = 'My Value'
```

creates an key:value pair on the session that is accessed automatically using the user's session cookie value.

If the modified session values aren't saved, you can try setting

```
request.session.modified = True
```

to tell Django that the session data changed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However it does not explain why I'm not able to retrieve the value of my session after the ResponseRedirect (either if I redirect to /portal/<token> or just /portal) when I host my django application remotely.

Comment: Did I understand it correctly that the session values get written into your session store database?

Comment: You are correct. The sessions values are stored into my database. These data include some user id information, email and other various info required by my service. The idea is to retrieve this value whenever is possible to point my users to some specific url (checking if userSecurId is present to confirm the user is approved to use the app)

Comment: And you are getting back all that data correctly after the redirect, except for the `userSecureId` value that you updated just before the redirect? Is the `userSecureId` value correctly stored in the database?

Comment: Locally, I'm able to retrieve everything. Remotely, I only get "None" for all my entries. And I already have confirmed the session value are valid by just going directly on the database and decoding the value (just basic b64 gave me all the required information). So the session is valid, Django retrieve the key successfully but I can not retrieve any values